# Dictionary vs Bunch of "if" with "return"

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I got confused between two approaches used in one of iOS apps. Lets say I can create a dictionary:

```
NSDictionary *numberDict = @{
    @"First" : [NSNumber numberWithInt:1],
    @"Second" : [NSNumber numberWithInt:2]};
```

Later on,

```
NSNumber *n = [numberDict objectForKey:@"First"]);
```

or just write a method which returns the number:

```
-(NSNumber *) numberMethod: (NSString *)number{
if([number isEqualToString @"First"]) return [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
if([number isEqualToString @"Second"]) return [NSNumber numberWithInt 2];
}
```

then,

```
NSNumber *n = [self numberMethod: @"First"];
```

Which way is more recommended (advantages vs. disadvantages), and which one shows better performance with more members then two like in my example?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Do you want to return int or NSNumber ?. `[NSNumber numberWithInt:42]` is a bit verbose. `@42` or `@(42)`are much more readable and produce the same thing.

Comment: These small details are not important since the example is fictive, it is more important about approaches. Please, edit if my question does not look coherent.

Comment: i don't think both have anything different, i rather the shorter one though

Comment: @Tj3n You should never go with a smaller piece of code because it doesn't **look different** from a larger piece of code that does the same thing. You must know how the code works and check if it is the proper way. Every application should be developed in a scalable manner. At some point someone else(or may be even yourself) will have to work on that code again, and if you have done something to **just make it work** and it is not the proper way, it might become a great headache.

Comment: @HarikrishnanT ofc i knew that -_- im saying in this case man...the if will run through each value cause decrease in performance...so the shorter one is prefered

Answer (score 4):

Accessing elements of a dictionary is supposed to be an `O(1)` operation. On the other hand, the `if` condition takes a considerably more amount of time for the same operation. So considering speed and neatness of code, `NSDictionary` is better. Another advantage is that, you can add any number of elements to the dictionary as you wish, so it is more dynamic(like in cases you are loading elements to the dictionary in run time, for example a web service response). This will make the code more flexible.

On the other hand, considering memory, the `NSDictionary` object obviously takes more memory as compared to the method, which is the only advantage I see with the method.

If you ask me what I would do, I would of course go with `NSDictionary`.

Comment: Also, second method allocate objects every time (if objects is more complex then NSNumber), but first method returns stored reference to cached objects.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you're trying to achieve. But in case you mentioned, it looks like you wanna have key-value pairs, in which case I would use what the language has to offer - the dictionary. `NSDictionary` has O(1) lookup time and is optimized for exactly what you want to do, remember you can use the Objective-C 2.0 approach for creating the dictionary:

```
NSDictionary *numberDict = @{@"First" : @1, @"Second" : @2 };
```

as well as accessing the values:

```
numberDict[@"First"]; // returns @1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think:

The `NSDictionary` takes more memory than `method`. Because the dictionary is stored. It's not good if there are too many big objects.

The `NSDictionary` runs faster than `method`. Because it is already loaded and using hashtag to access values.

I will refer the `NSDictionary` approach, because it is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Using `NSDictionary`/`NSMutableDictionary` is a more recommended way.

```
NSDictionary *numberDict = @{
    @"First" : @1,
    @"Second": @2
};

NSNumber *n = numberDict[@"First"];
```

- If you use method for this, then you would end up writing a lot of `if` statements and every time if you want to add a new value, you have to write entire `if` statement again. Whereas shorthand notation for `NSDictionary` is very concise as you can see above.
- While calling method, you have to specify the class object i.e. `self` and you have to write the long method name. Whereas you can take advantage of subscript notation while accessing a value from `NSDictionary`.
- You can enumerate a `NSDictionary`
- You can take advantage of other methods written for `NSDicationary`, such as `allKeys`, `allValues`, `writeToFile`, `initFromFile`, `count`, `initWithDictionary`, and the list goes on.
- Lastly, if you are using `NSMutableDictionary` then you have the advantage of modifying values at a later point of time in the code.

The only advantage with methods would be that they will not occupy any memory.